# DataUpdater and ActiveObject classes are not supported in AnyLogic 8

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic, modeling, agent-based-modeling

I want to study and customize agent-based model in AnyLogic which was developed about 10 years ago in AnyLogic 6.6 (version).

The model is opening in AnyLogic 8.7.12, but can not be compiled correctly. There are some errors occurring because of such classes as ***DataUpdater()*** and ***ActiveObject()*** are not available in this version. The author of the model said, that in previous version it worked correctly.

1. How can I optimize the code for the current version to compile this model successfully?
2. And how can I resolve the 3rd error about method update(DataSet)?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cery6.png)

Answer (score 0):

The `ActiveObject` type has been entirely removed and is now replaced with the `Agent` type.

So you either replace all references to it using `Agent` or remove it entirely.

Which one is easier/faster simply depends on the model details, hard to say.

Comment: Thank you, and what can I do with DataUpdater, which replacement can be here?

Comment: No idea what that is, tbh.